# How to make Python remember the contents of a file without saving it to local disk?

Tags: python, variables, url

I have a script that downloads a text file then extract all URLs then make a new file to save these URLs in. But rather than saving it to local disk, I would much rather prefer Python to remember the contents of the text file, perhaps even make it equal to a variable, so I can use for the next step. That way, there's no need to keep saving files to local disk and add commands later to delete these files.

Is that possible, and if so, how?

Here's the code:

```
import urllib.request
import os
import re  

# download text file to disk
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt", "iso_input.txt")

# extract all URLs from input file then insert into new output file
with open("iso_input.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        urls = re.findall('https?://[^\s<>"]+[|www\.^\s<>"]+', line)
        print(*urls, file=open("iso_output.txt", "a"))
```

Comment: You are using the legacy urlretrieve function, but there are other functions and classes in the module that don't use files. Here is the module doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html

Comment: Can you explain your code? Your actual code enters in infinite loop because from a side you read a file and on the other side you append data in this same file.

Comment: My apologies! I fixed it. Should've said `iso_output.txt`.

Comment: Do you know your input file does not contain any url?

Comment: You're right, but when I do put a text file that contains URLs, it saves it to local disk. I was thinking perhaps there's a way I can have Python "remember" the contents of the file then use it for the next step (URL extraction) without the need to save and then later delete these files.

Comment: "perhaps even make it equal to a variable" I don't understand the problem. I see `urls = re.findall('https?://[^\s<>"]+[|www\.^\s<>"]+', line)` already in the code. How exactly is `urls` not already what you want?

Comment: It seems like what you're trying to get at is: each time through the loop, you get a list of values, and you want to know how to put all those values into the *same* list? Well - how do you *normally* add values to an *existing* list? Can you see a way to use this technique to solve the problem?

Comment: My issue is with saving the files to local disk. I don't want to do that. I just want Python to parse the file's contents and save them to a variable without saving them on the local disk. That way, I don't have to delete these temporary files later, you know what I mean?

Comment: Check the docs for the most fundamental python type: [the list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). Use `append`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO):

> A text stream using an in-memory text buffer.

```
# Open input file and output "file"
with open("iso_input.txt", "r") as file, io.StringIO() as output:
    for line in file:
        urls = re.findall('https?://[^\s<>"]+[|www\.^\s<>"]+', line)
        print(*urls, file=output)  # print to in-memory buffer

    # Save "output file content" as variable
    urls = output.getvalue()

# Do something with the retrieved urls
print(urls)
```

On a side note, `https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/iso_8859-1.txt` doesn't contain any URLs, as [@Corralien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15239951/corralien) has correctly pointed out

Comment: Thank you very very much!!

Comment: @facialrecognition You're welcome, glad I could help :-)